# problem with Switch Case

Tags: iphone, objective-c, switch-statement

I am creating a UIView dynamically and adding a scrollview in it. What I want is to create mutiple scrollviews and add them by using SWITCH Case.

I am passing an integer value called num on IBAction of a button on UIView. and calling the function to create a scrollview.

```
-(IBAction) button1pressed{
    num = 1;
    NSLog(@"value %d",num);
}
```

I have 6 IBActions like this with different values of num from 1 to 6. I want to Switch the value of num.

```
-(void)add_scrollview{
    Switch(num) {
        Case:1 {
            NSLog(@"case 1 executed");              
            break;      
        }
        Case:2 {
            NSLog(@"case 2 executed");
            break;
        } 
        Case :3 {
            NSLog(@"case 3 executed");
            break;
        }
        default:{
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

every time i click a button, it takes its respective "num" value and performs the switch. But, when i click the another button,it is not switching the value of num. It takes num's previous value.

Comment: Not to start a holy war, but it seems the stack overflow code formatting prefers spaces over tabs...

Comment: Does that accurately reflect the code? If so, it shouldn't even compile. "Switch" and "Case" shouldn't be capitalized, and the case labels come before the colons, not after (e.g. "1:", not ":1"). Beyond that, the sample is a little too minimal. There doesn't look to be enough code to say what is going on. Please create and post a minimal test case: it should be as short as possible, yet enough code to be complete & self contained, and should suffer the same problems as the code you're trying to debug.

Comment: What outis said is very good advice. It's the best way to get a problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

case and switch should both be lower case. And the correct syntax is

```
case 1: {
}
```

not

```
case:1{
}
```

If it still doesnt work i would add an argument to your method with the num instead of having it as a property.

```
-(void)add_scrollviewWithId:(int) id;
```